# Case insensitive property mapping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

When serializing a MongoDB document to a POCO is there any way to make properties map case insensitive? For example I'd like this document:

```
{
    "id": "1"
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

to map to this class:

```
public MyObj
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Foo {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do that I think you will have 2 options.

The first would be to write out a class map manually

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Foo).SetElementName("foo");
});
```

The second would be to decorate your class with the following attributes

```
public class MyObj
{
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [BsonElement("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The CSharp driver team have a good tutorial on serialization on the following link

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/

#### Update

I have just tried the following and this works for me, obviously I'm sure this is a much more simplified version of your code but taking a guess at how it might look.

I have registered the two class maps separately and added the BsonKnownType to the base class.

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(GeoJSONObject))]
public class Point
{
    public string Coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class GeoJSONObject : Point
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cn = new MongoConnectionStringBuilder("server=localhost;database=MyTestDB;");
    var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionStringBuilder(cn);
    var client = new MongoClient(settings);

    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Point>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Coordinates).SetElementName("coordinates");                   
    });

    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<GeoJSONObject>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Type).SetElementName("type");
    });

    var result = client.GetServer()
              .GetDatabase("MyTestDB")
              .GetCollection("MyCol")
              .Find(Query.EQ("type", BsonValue.Create("xxxx")));
}
```

Comment: I gave this a try and ran into a bit of a problem. I have a derived class `Point` which extends a base class `GeoJSONObject`. `Point` has property `Coordinates` and `GeoJSONObject` has property `Type` both of which I want to map to lower case equivalents. If I try to register `Coordinates` on `Point` it works fine. If I try to register `Type` on `Point` I get a null reference error. If I try to  register `Type` on `GeoJSONObject` it works. But if I try to register both `Coordinates` on `Point` and `Type` on `GeoJSONObject`, IIS crashes with no helpful info in the event viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I tried this, but it's still not quite working for me. Sorry, I should have mentioned earlier, but I'm trying to use this NuGet package (https://nuget.org/packages/GeoJSON.Net) so I don't have access to directly add attributes to the properties. I tried implementing the initialization code version of your code per this document (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver), but I'm still getting the same results I mentioned above.

Answer (score 7):

I see that it is old question, but people still may search it. At least I found it while was asking the same question.

The `CamelCaseElementNameConvention` can be used to apply this globally.

```
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());

ConventionRegistry.Register("Camel case convention", pack, t => true);
```

Documentation: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/

Comment: This is the best answer and it has very hidden lol.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/data-formats/poco/#set-field-names